# python scrabble score calculation

Tags: python

[I am a beginner to python and I'm trying to make a simple scrabble score calculation program. May I know how to get the letter score from the letterScore function and add it to the scrabbleScore function? Thanks a lot for your help! Please have a look on the screenshot for the program I have tried~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoHAH.png)

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a screenshot of it

Comment: Please update your question with the text of the code you have tried, not just an image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks good, however I would recommend using a dictionary to get the letter scores:

```
values = { ('a':1), ('b':3), ('c':3), ... , ('z':10) }
```

then you can find the score much faster by using `values[letter]` inside your letterScore function.

Now to get the score from your function, you need to call the following inside the bottom for loop, above the totalScore calculation

```
score = letterScore(letter)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, when I tried the code above(I've not changed into the dictionary yet), python returned "string index out of range"

Comment: At the bottom of the letterScore function where you have score = value[0][1], it should be value[1]

Comment: oh yes, done! Thanks so much for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move `score = letterScore(letter)` to the inside of your loop in `scrabbleScore`

Comment: Done! Thanks so much for your answer!